# NodeJS Request Parameter not showing value

Tags: node.js, parameters, request

I have the following url to reset a password using a token:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/reset/a513293ba51df393568cebfab178754eb284bb62
```

I have the following route handler:

```
router.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {...
```

For some reason my request parameter does not display the value in my route. 
`req.params.token` displays: `reset`, not `a513293ba51df393568cebfab178754eb284bb62`

I must be missing something very obvious because all my other pages and routes work fine.

After spending some more time on this I think I might have an idea why my req object is not working. It must be because of the async call. How can I get this to work?

My full route is this:

```
router.post("/reset/:token", function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
      function(done) {
          console.log(req.params.token);
          UserModel.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
          if (!user) {
            return res.redirect('/login');
          }

          user.password = req.body.password;
          user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
          user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

          user.save(function(err) {
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
              done(err, user);
            });
          });
        });
      },
      function(user, done) {
        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: 'SendGrid',
          auth: {
            user: 'xxx',
            pass: 'xxx'
          }
        });
        var mailOptions = {
          to: user.email,
          from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
          subject: 'Your password has been changed',
          text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
            'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
        };
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
          console.log('Success! Your password has been changed.');
          done(err);
        });
      }
    ], function(err) {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

Comment: are you using express router or have a route like /:id/:token before /reset/:token ?

Comment: Did the router executed?

Comment: Yes, I'm using express router.  The router did execute. The only other similar route I have is : `router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {`

Comment: @mo_maat Print out your `req.params` object in the router `console.log(req.params);`

Comment: I already did. It shows `reset` as the value for `req.params.token`.

Comment: @mo_maat I think it would be return a json object :-?

Comment: Isn't the URL you are calling just a standard get request?  `router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {...`?

Comment: It turns out that the issue I was having was because my form had the following `<form action="reset" method="POST">`. Setting the action to `""` allowed my parameter from the url to be passed through.